# Writing and reading from a binary file

Tags: c++, file, binary

I'm trying to learn how to write to a binary file and then read the info back into variables. I'm trying to make the info in c3 & c4 the same as c1 & c2 by having it read from the binary file. I've searched and tried for many hours, but I can't figure out what else I'm doing wrong. Please help.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Cat {
    char name[50];
    int age;
};

//----- TEXT I/O -----//
void display(Cat& cat) {
    cout << cat.name << endl;
    cout << cat.age << endl;
}

//----- BINARY I/O -----//
void writeBinaryData(ofstream& binaryFile, Cat& cat) {
    binaryFile.write(cat.name, sizeof(char[50]));
    binaryFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&cat.age), sizeof(int));
}

void readBinaryData(ifstream& binaryFile, Cat& cat) {
    binaryFile.read(cat.name, sizeof(char[50]));
    binaryFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&cat.age), sizeof(int));
}

int main() {
    Cat c1, c2, c3, c4;
    // c1's name is Ben and age is 2
    strcpy(c1.name, "Ben");
    c1.age = 2;
    // c2's name is Willard and age is 3
    strcpy(c2.name, "Willard");
    c2.age = 3;
    // display c1 & c2
    display(c1);
    display(c2);
    // read and write c1 & c2 to binary data file
    ofstream binOut("catfarm.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
    writeBinaryData(binOut, c1);
    writeBinaryData(binOut, c2);
    // read from binary file into c3 & c4
    ifstream binIn("catfarm.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
    readBinaryData(binIn, c3);
    readBinaryData(binIn, c4);
    display(c3);
    display(c4);
    return 0;
}
```

Right now the output looks like this:

```
Ben
2
Willard
3

32701

32701
```

But it should look like this:

```
Ben
2
Willard
3
Ben
2
Willard
3
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You should close the output file stream before opening the input one (wrap the read / write instructions in a scope to trigger the destructor of the filestream). Most likely the read ops are failing. (Either way, checking that the filestream is valid and that the read ops succeeded is always a good place to start)

Comment: You could use one binary write statement:  `binaryFile.write((char *) &cat, sizeof(cat));`.  If there is any padding between the variables, this write will contain the padding.  It may be worth sacrificing some space for a more efficient method.

Comment: Borgleader, that was it! I just needed to close the output filestream first, and that made it work perfectly. I never would have figured that out. Thank you! I would +1 your comment but it's not letting me because my question was put on hold. Sorry.

Comment: `sizeof(char[50])` is hilarious (useless use of cat); it's just `50`.  Better would be `sizeof(cat.name)`.

Comment: @John Zwinck. Thanks. Still new to a lot of this.